# ¿Cómo hacer que un audio se detenga al iniciar otro en HTML5 Y JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Mi código de JavaScript:

```
     <script>
  function playA(){
       var audioA = document.getElementById("audioA");
       audioA.play();
       }
function playB(){
       var audioB = document.getElementById("audioB");
       audioB.play();
       }
function playC(){
       var audioC = document.getElementById("audioC");
       audioC.play();
       }  

   </script>
```

Mi html no tiene nada, solo head el titulo y ya

Comment: Incluye tambien tu HTML

Comment: mi html no tiene nada

Comment: A juzgar por el código, tu HTML sí debería incluir algo, porque en tus funciones estás llamando a elementos de audio, cada uno con su `id`.

Comment: @Helpme no modifiques tu pregunta, si quieres agradecer basta con que lo hagas en los comentarios

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta está muy incompleta, pues falta todo tu html y la parte de JS donde estableces las funciones en los componentes, por favor revisa este ejemplo (usando videos por conveniencia en lugar de audios)

```js
function pausaTodo(){
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].pause();
  }
}
  function playA(){
     pausaTodo();
       document.getElementById("video1").play();
       }
function playB(){
pausaTodo();
       document.getElementById("video2").play();
       }
function playC(){
pausaTodo();
       document.getElementById("video3").play();
       }  
       
var btnp1=document.getElementById("btnPlay1");
var btnp2=document.getElementById("btnPlay2");
var btnp3=document.getElementById("btnPlay3");
  
btnp1.onclick= function(){playA()};
btnp2.onclick= function(){playB()};
btnp3.onclick= function(){playC()};
```

```html
<p>
Video 1
</p>
<video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<p>
Video 2
</p>
<video id="video2" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<p>
Video 3
</p>
<video id="video3" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br>
<button id="btnPlay1">Play 1</button>
<button id="btnPlay2">Play 2</button>
<button id="btnPlay3">Play 3</button>

<br>
a
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para detener un audio antes de que el otro empieze, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
function playA(){
   var audioB = document.getElementById("audioB");
   audioB.pause();
   audioB.currentTime = 0;
   var audioA = document.getElementById("audioA");
   audioA.play();
}
```